# why after applying yui context reset my webkit number input spin button stopped working

Tags: html, css, yui

I have added style sheet like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.13.0/build/cssreset-context/cssreset-context.css" type="text/css" />
<link href="/static/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

and i had

```
input::-webkit-inner-spin- {
-webkit-appearance: none;
margin: 0; 
}
```

inside my style.css to remove spin button from my number inputs.

But after I applied the link to yui reset, the code from my input::-webkit..... has stopped working.
 I am not able to make it work again, can someone help and explain me.

Comment: You need to give the html or it is impossible to answer. Here's for starters, now add the html: http://jsbin.com/erOvOvo/1/edit

Answer (score 1):

This my guess as you did not provide any code. I think this is related to CSS specificity rules.

The yui cssreset applys style to `.yui3-cssreset` class.

Since you are giving styles on the html element the rules from yui cssreset are considered to be more specific and given higher priority.

Read this to get a better idea on how CSS rules are prioritized

[CSS Specificity](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/)

Comment: the article helped alot. Actually after applying yui3 reset, i had to apply property to -webkit-outer-spin also and not only -webkit-inner-spin. This works